# What kind of paint should be used to protect gas meter?

Tags: painting, gas, meter

During our home inspection, the inspector mentioned that the gas meter wasn't painted and could be subject to rusting later but he didn't elaborate on what paint to use.  Anyone have suggestions here?

Are there paint types specifically made for this?

-M

Comment: Check with your gas company.  They may own the meter (per local laws) and so they'd be responsible for replacing it if it gets rusted.  And they not be happy if you go painting their property without permission.  If they let you do it, they would probably have recommendations.

Comment: SoCal Gas meters are prepainted, but they do use a meter gray paint to paint the pipes to match. Did not copy down brand name of paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one at my house is new and it appears to be powder-coated. I'd let the gas company fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

Gas meters will be painted at the gas-meter factory.  When factories (with an institutional customer) paint things in production, they use the very best paints, which would be a 2-part LPU over 2-part epoxy primer.  Or lately, powdercoating with chemicals of similar quality.  (they jack the cure temperature to 400F, so they can sell it to you pre-mixed in one can, but you must oven cure it.)

You can't touch that kind of durability with any consumer-available paints.

Such paints have a very tough outer sheen that won't take paint.  If you want to repaint it because you don't like the color, you would need to scuff up the paint, e.g. with a Scotchbrite pad.